# QGIS: How to displace points close to each other (but not overlapping) and save as a layer?

Tags: qgis, printing

I'm preparing a point vector file for printing, and I would like to displace the points within it so that the markers will be far enough apart that they do not overlap. I am not using QGIS to render the print map, so I would like to output a vector file where the points have been displaced.

The QGIS Processing plugin has a Points Displacement algorithm that works great for overlapping points that are on the exact same point, but is there a way to do this with a buffer? So that the output file has no points that are, say, within 50 meters of each other?